# Adding two bootstrap modals in a single page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add 2 bootstrap modals in a single page.But I am unable to add it,Only one modal is working.I need to add 2 modals for two buttons.What I am doing wrong?Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <button class="addFavourite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Favourite</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 smsDetails">
    <a href="#addFavourite" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">Send SMS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 smsDetails">
    <div class="modal fade " id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="post-comment">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>To:</label><span>ms.tech10@gmail.com</span>
            <br>
            <label>Message:</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
            <button>Send Message</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default favouriteConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addFavourite">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h4 class="popupHead">Add Load Route to Favourite</h4>
            <p>This is a unique feature available only for registered users that allows user to repost the posted load for the given route again and again without the hassle to repost the load. This is helpful if the user has same load requirement frequently.
              </p>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="day">1 day
              <input type="radio" name="day">2 day
              <input type="radio" name="day">3 day
            </div>
            <p><strong>Note:</strong> The load will be reposted repeatedly till the time same is not removed from favourite list.</p>
            <button class="favouriteConfirm">Add to Favourite and Confirm</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default favouriteConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Complete code here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/981qjkwv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for both, you can only reference an ID a single time per page and you haven't applied `data-toggle="modal"` to your `href`.

See [Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

**Working Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="col-xs-12 ">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFavourite">Add Favourite</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 ">
    <a class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Send SMS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 smsDetails">
    <div class="modal fade " id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="post-comment">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>To:</label><span>ms.tech10@gmail.com</span>
            <br>
            <label>Message:</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
            <button>Send Message</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default favouriteConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addFavourite" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addFavourite">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h4 class="popupHead">Add Load Route to Favourite</h4>
            <p>This is a unique feature available only for registered users that allows user to repost the posted load for the given route again and again without the hassle to repost the load. This is helpful if the user has same load requirement frequently.
            </p>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="day">1 day
              <input type="radio" name="day">2 day
              <input type="radio" name="day">3 day
            </div>
            <p><strong>Note:</strong> The load will be reposted repeatedly till the time same is not removed from favourite list.</p>
            <button class="favouriteConfirm">Add to Favourite and Confirm</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default favouriteConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```